# Postgres pg_dumpall consistency across databases that are backed up

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to backup all of the databases on a hyperscaler managed postgres server as of a certain time in order to maintain data consistency between the databases with either pg_dumpall, pg_dump  or something else?

**Background:**
With the utilization of micro-services, an application may have many databases associated to it on a single hyperscaler managed postgres server.  The hyperscalers do perform a functional snapshot backup; however, when  a hyperscaler managed postgres server is accidentally deleted, the postgres backups are lost as well.  These hyperscalers provide locks to prevent accidental deletes of a postgres server and mention that their support teams can be contacted to restore a deleted server, however, we still had a postgres server get deleted.  We were able to recover by contacting the hyperscalers support team but would like to have a second way of backing up a hyperscaler managed postgres server.

I realize that the micro-services should be able to auto-recover to a data consistent point but the reality is that many of the micro-services have not been designed nor written to that requirement.  I really do not want to get into the aspect of micro-service design and want to retain this to be a DBA backup question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pg_dumpall` will *not* take a consistent backup across all databases. Each database backup will be consistent, but the snapshots for the backups of the different databases will be taken at different times.

If you need a consistent backup across several databases in a single cluster, use an online file system backup with `pg_basebackup`.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  Do you know if pg_basebackup is allowed on managed cloud postgres instances for either Azure or GCP?  on Azure, it would be a postgres flexible server.

Comment: No, you typically are not allowed to run `pg_basebackup` on a hosted database. They don't allow replication connections to lock you in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pg_basebackup which most of the PostgreSQL DBA’s would end up using on a daily basis be it via scripts or manually. This creates the base backup of the database which can help in recovering in multiple situations. This takes an online backup of the database and hence is very useful when being used in production

you can review [this](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgresql-database-backup-recovery-what-works-wal-pitr) for more details

Comment: thanks for your reply too. Do you know if pg_basebackup is allowed on managed cloud postgres instances for either Azure or GCP? on Azure, it would be a postgres flexible server.  I briefly went through the docs and could not find that command for managed postgres instances.  Azure may want you to setup replication rather than pg_basebackup.  Not sure though.  Still investigating.

Comment: They don't allow to user pg_basebackup but you can create read replica from azure managed PostgreSQL in your local DC.